# Selenium Manager is not obtaining chromedriver on corporate Virtual Machine with selenium 4.14

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have updated to the latest version of Selenium (C# 4.14.0) to be able to use selenium manager and not have to use a webdrivermanager package to manage the chromedriver.exe files. When I try to run IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(); I get an exception saying that selenium is unable to obtain chrome using selenium manager. This happens on the virtual machines that I test with but not my local machine. The following is the exception that I am getting

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error starting process: \\...\Debug\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --output json ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Selenium Manager process exited abnormally with 65 code: \\...\Debug\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --output json
Standard Output >>
{
  "logs": [
    {
      "level": "ERROR",
      "timestamp": 1697134586,
      "message": "error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)"
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "code": 65,
    "message": "error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)",
    "driver_path": "",
    "browser_path": ""
  }
}
```

This is the code that I am running that is having the issue

```
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I am expecting the corresponding version of chromedriver.exe to be downloaded and opened to use for my testing, but instead I just get the exception saying that there was an error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json) when I run this on my corporate virtual machine, but it works on my local machine.